# How to start firefox in offline mode from a command line?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-cache

I would like to start Firefox with a selected profile (using `--new-instance -P profileName` flags), but in offline mode. How can I accomplish that when there's no `--offline` parameter or anything similar available?

Comment: Load a local page. That works for Chrome and Edge (but I have not tried by command line)

Comment: Opening a local page by clicking on an html file opens Firefox in online mode by default. The opened page can successfully make external requests.

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to be simple, just start firefox with the command line switch -offline (or /offline or --offline)

Not sure if this is documented. Tried it on Windows 10, works unless I am missing something. FF 97.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

The setting, *File | Work Offline* does *not* appear to be persistent, i.e., if one closes *Firefox* while offline, on reopening it, it's online.

However, you could configure *Windows Firewall* to block incoming and outgoing *Firefox* communication.

- Create the two rules in *Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*.
- Using *Regedit*, export those two rules from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules` to a file named *FFoxOffline.reg* or a similar descriptive name. You might export each rule separately and combine into one file.
- Copy that .reg file, naming it descriptively, e.g., *FFoxOnline.reg*.
- Edit that copy to set `Active=FALSE` for each rule.

Then start *Firefox* using a .bat file to first apply the appropriate .reg file and then to start the correct Firefox profile.

This might not give you *exactly* what you requested, since you might still need to set *Firefox* offline after starting, and it prevents internet access to all *Firefox* instances with executable stored in the same location.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It might be a clever workaround, but I don't even use windows :( That's why I am looking for a command argument that would do the same thing as File > Work offline.

Comment: @pineapple500, you'd get better answers if you provide more info, e.g., OS.